# Do a Sum and a Difference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope someone could guide in the correct path . It's my first class in SQL.

```
SELECT distinct
                a.LICENSEID,
                a.license,
                a.business_name,
                a,year
                a.TOTAL_AMOUNT_PAID,
                SUM(e.COMPUTED_AMOUNT) over (partition by e.LICENSEID) as AMOUNT_OWNED,
FROM vw_business AS a
INNER JOIN vw_fees AS e ON e.LICENSEID = a.LICENSEID
WHERE LICENSE = '1000'
AND(e.STATUS='BILLED' OR e.STATUS='PAID')
```

This will give me a result like this:

```
LICENSEID   LICENSE   BUSINESS_NAME   YEAR   TOTAL_AMOUT_PAID   AMOUNT_OWNED
1CA6918B    1000      CORTANA         2016   0.00               1000.00
EE6DBDD0    1000      CORTANA         2017   1000.00            1000.00
```

Basically, I want to add another column to calculate the Total Balance which should be the difference between AMOUNT_OWNED and TOTAL_AMOUNT_PAID. I tried adding another line after SUM like this:

```
(AMOUNT_OWNED - TOTAL_AMOUNT_PAID) AS TOTAL_BALANCED,
```

However, I get an error that doesn't recognized the TOTAL_BALANCED. I also tried adding the entire line of the SUM again with no luck.

Can you guys guide in the correct path? If this is possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Alias` names cannot be referred in same `select` query. You need to write the `sum over()` window aggregate again to find difference

Try this way

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.LICENSEID,
                a.license,
                a.business_name,
                a.year, -- Here it is should be . instead of ,
                a.TOTAL_AMOUNT_PAID,
                Sum(e.COMPUTED_AMOUNT)OVER (partition BY e.LICENSEID) AS AMOUNT_OWNED,
                a.TOTAL_AMOUNT_PAID - Sum(e.COMPUTED_AMOUNT)
                                        OVER (
                                          partition BY e.LICENSEID) AS TOTAL_BALANCED
FROM   vw_business AS a
       INNER JOIN vw_fees AS e
               ON e.LICENSEID = a.LICENSEID
WHERE  LICENSE = '1000'
       AND e.STATUS IN ( 'BILLED', 'PAID' )  -- use IN clause
```

or use derived table, this is a better option when the expression is big. Query will be more readable

```
SELECT LICENSEID,
       license,
       business_name,
       year,
       TOTAL_AMOUNT_PAID,
       AMOUNT_OWNED,
       TOTAL_AMOUNT_PAID - AMOUNT_OWNED as TOTAL_BALANCED
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT a.LICENSEID,
                        a.license,
                        a.business_name,
                        a.year,-- Here it is should be . instead of ,
                        a.TOTAL_AMOUNT_PAID,
                        Sum(e.COMPUTED_AMOUNT)OVER (partition BY e.LICENSEID) AS AMOUNT_OWNED
        FROM   vw_business AS a
               INNER JOIN vw_fees AS e
                       ON e.LICENSEID = a.LICENSEID
        WHERE  LICENSE = '1000'
               AND e.STATUS IN ( 'BILLED', 'PAID' ) -- use IN clause 
       ) a
```